# Why SIGPIPE doesn't occur when the read end of a pipe is closed?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I'm trying to write a program with two processes:

One process generates some a + b problems and print it to its stdout (like `printf("%d %d\n", a, b)`), and gets the answer from another process through stdin, and log the answer to log.txt. When all the problems are asked, the process will print out "-1 -1" to indicate the end of the problems.

Another process receives the a + b problems through stdin (like `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b)`), and prints the answer to its stdout. When `a = b = -1` the process exits.

I'm using two pairs of pipe to connect the two processes. I use `dup2` to bind the pipes with stdin and stdout. My source code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

// Get a + b question through stdin, and print answer to stdout
void calc_a_plus_b() {
    int a, b;
    while (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) > 0)
    {
        if (a == -1 && b == -1)
            break;
        printf("%d\n", a + b);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}

// Ask a + b through stdout, and get answer through stdin
// Log answer to log.txt
void ask_a_plus_b() {
    FILE* log = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    int i, a, b, c;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a = i; b = i + 1;
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &c);
        fprintf(log, "%d\n", c);
    }
    printf("-1 -1\n");
    fclose(log);
}

int main()
{
    pid_t ask_pid, calc_pid, term_pid;
    int ask_to_calc[2], calc_to_ask[2];    // Two pairs of pipe
    int status;

    // Create pipe
    pipe(ask_to_calc); pipe(calc_to_ask);

    // Create calculate process
    calc_pid = fork();
    if (calc_pid == 0) {
        // Close useless pipe
        close(ask_to_calc[1]);
        close(calc_to_ask[0]);

        // Bind pipe to stdin and stdout
        dup2(ask_to_calc[0], 0);
        dup2(calc_to_ask[1], 1);
        close(ask_to_calc[0]);
        close(calc_to_ask[1]);

        calc_a_plus_b();
        return 0;
    }

    // Create ask process
    ask_pid = fork();
    if (ask_pid == 0) {
        // Close useless pipe
        close(ask_to_calc[0]);
        close(calc_to_ask[1]);

        // Bind pipe to stdin and stdout
        dup2(calc_to_ask[0], 0);
        dup2(ask_to_calc[1], 1);

        ask_a_plus_b();
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait for children to exit
    while ((term_pid = wait(&status)) > 0) {
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
        {
            // If child stopped but hasn't exited, ignore
            continue;
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            // Child exited due to signal
            printf("%s terminated due to signal %d\n", ask_pid == term_pid ? "ask" : "calc", WTERMSIG(status));
        } else {
            // Child exited normally
            printf("%s terminated normally\n", ask_pid == term_pid ? "ask" : "calc");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs normally, and prints out

```
calc terminated normally
ask terminated normally
```

From `man 7 pipe` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) I know that, when all the file descriptors to the read end of a pipe is closed, and another process still tries to write to this pipe, a SIGPIPE will occur. So I decided to remove all the code in `calc_a_plus_b` and see what will happen.

Surprisingly, SIGPIPE doesn't occur. The program only prints out

```
calc terminated normally
```

after that the program is stuck. I guess this is because the `printf` in `ask_a_plus_b` is blocked.

I think I've closed all the file descriptors to the read end of the pipe `ask_to_calc` (I've bound the pipe to the stdin of the calculating process, but the process has exited so its stdin is also closed right?), so why SIGPIPE doesn't occur when the asking process tries to write to the pipe?

Comment: Please don’t tag c++ *and* c. You’re using one or the other, so tag accordingly.

Comment: *unrelated to your question*, but `while (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) > 0)` -> `while (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) == 2)` or you should initialize `a` and `b` before entering the loop.

Comment: Two things. 1. SIGPIPE isn't sent until the second write to a closed pipe (the first one returns 0, second one generates SIGPIPE). 2. Your parent process still has the pipes open.

Comment: You are right... After closing the pipes in the parent process, the asking process is now terminated due to SIGPIPE. Sorry for the mistake, it's so awkward...-_-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Art for the comment. I forgot to close the pipes in the parent process-_-"

After closing the pipes in the parent process, the asking process is now terminated due to SIGPIPE.